# Change formatted file per record

Tags: python, format

I'm looking to change a formatted file that looks like this:

```
1182659 Sample05 22
1182659 Sample33 14
4758741 Sample05 74
4758741 Sample33 2
3652147 Sample05 8
3652147 Sample33 34
```

To this:

```
       Sample05 Sample33 
1182659 22 14
4758741 74 2
3652147 8 34
```

One way I see to do it, is to use a double indexed dictionary but I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this before I go in.

Answer (score 1):

Without `pandas`, but with `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = """
1182659 Sample05 22
1182659 Sample33 14
4758741 Sample05 74
4758741 Sample33 2
3652147 Sample05 8
3652147 Sample33 34
"""

groups = groupby((line.split() for line in data.splitlines() if line), key=lambda v: v[0])

rows = []
headers = []
for g, v in groups:
    v = list(v)
    for i in v:
        if i[1] not in headers:
            headers.append(i[1])
    rows.append([g] + [i[-1] for i in v])

print('\t'+ '\t'.join(headers))
for row in rows:
    for value in row:
        print(value, end='\t')
    print()
```

Prints:

```
    Sample05    Sample33
1182659 22  14  
4758741 74  2   
3652147 8   34
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

# if the delimeter is a space
df = pd.read_csv("<path to file>.txt", sep=" ", header=None)
df.set_index([0, 1])[2].unstack()
```

Output:

```
1        Sample05  Sample33
0
1182659        22        14
3652147         8        34
4758741        74         2
```